# array values that auto increment by a set value (eg if 1st is echo $myarray[5]; the next would be echo $myarray[5+5]; so really $myarray[10];)

Tags: php, arrays, auto-increment

Got an array thats like this..

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Order Number
            [1] => Item 1 Colour
            [2] => Buyer Name
            [3] => Item 1 Name
            [4] => Item 1 Variation
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Order Number
            [1] => Item 1 Colour
            [2] => Buyer Name
            [3] => Item 1 Name
            [4] => Item 1 Variation
            [5] => Order Number
            [6] => Item 2 Colour
            [7] => Buyer Name
            [8] => Item 2 Name
            [9] => Item 2 Variation

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Order Number
            [1] => Item 1 Colour
            [2] => Buyer Name
            [3] => Item 1 Name
            [4] => Item 1 Variation
            [5] => Order Number
            [6] => Item 2 Colour
            [7] => Buyer Name
            [8] => Item 2 Name
            [9] => Item 2 Variation
            [10] => Order Number
            [11] => Item 3 Colour
            [12] => Buyer Name
            [13] => Item 3 Name
            [14] => Item 3 Variation

        )
}
```

This is showing 3 dummy orders and in this example, the first order has 1 item, the second-order has 2 items and the 3rd order has 3 items. as you can see the more items added the array just gets longer for that item and the numbers always increase in a set number of blocks. ie the title for item one in order 2 in the example above is [3] then for item 2 it is [8] (so same as before plus 5) 
then in order example 3 its [3], [8] & [13] so basically always plus 5 from the prev number ref

So can there a way to echo a value plus 5 of the prev value and keep doing that at all

like

```
$item1title = $myarray[5];
$item2title = $item1title[+5];
$item3title = $item2title[+5];

echo $item1title; 
echo $item2title; 
echo $item2title;
```

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off redesigning that array to hold an array of items. This way you have unnecessary duplication (I assume within one array all order ids are the same, as well as the buyer's name) + it'd be much easier to iterate over the items.

Comment: I'd spend my time thinking of how to better structure the data from the beginning.  Like having each order by an array with order-specific details at the top level, and then an "items" sub-array that is an array of all of the items in the order, where each item is then also an array of the item details

Comment: I agree it would save duplication that way however I do have to keep the arrays as is in blocks of the same amounts that add on (like I have it now), as it's important the later referenced values called by these number are always the same as described .

Ie item 2 is value can always be found at item 1 plus x (depending on my block sizes)

Comment: Don't postpone restructuring a dataset just because you'd also have to refactor the code that references it. Any additional functionality you may have to develop in the future is just going to get more complicated (like this one right now). It should never, ever be this complicated to access data.

Comment: Sounds like you need to start over.  You'll thank yourself later.  What you have now is going to cause you way more frustration than taking the time to do it right.  Otherwise, you'll probably just end up right back here asking another question about how to do some completely arbitrary manipulation to a poorly-constructed array.

Comment: To your specific question though, have you actually _tried_ anything?  Like a loop?  Also, using variables like `$item3title` isn't a great idea either.  Do you really know how many items there are always going to be?  Probably not.  So how are you creating those variable names?

Comment: Both fair comments, I think my issue is if I don't have them in blocks of set number then I don't know (as the data changes each time) what number to echo for each line I need at that point. This is making invoices from a CSV that's turned into an array then called for each item as an invoice line. I am happy to re-think and re-write it but just can't think how the structure could/would work (ie how to best rearrange the array) so id still know the reference points ?

Comment: You might want to present your current code in a question on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: The whole idea is that if you re-do it you won't be accessing arbitrary numeric indexes at all.  Instead, you'd be looping over an array of orders, each of which contains (in addition to order details) an array of items, each of which contains item details.  You do know about associative arrays, right?

Comment: What Patrick is saying is right on point. You need to change your view; instead of thinking "I need to do this action for order 1, order 2 and order 3", you should be thinking "I need to do this action for *each* order". If the action is the same, then you don't have to worry about directly accessing an element and you enter the realm of loops - repeating the same task for every element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how you could build your array in a more useful way.  As mentioned in the comments, we create a main orders array.  Inside that array, we have an entry for each order.  Each of those orders is also an array, and contains the details of the order, and also the items.  The items are contained in an array, with each item as an entry in the array.  Each item is itself also an array, with the entries being the item details.

```
$orders = array(
    array(
        "orderNum" => 123,
        "buyerId" => 111,
        "items" => array(
            array(
                "id" => 321,
                "name" => "Item One",
                "color" => "red"
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "orderNum" => 456,
        "buyerId" => 444,
        "items" => array(
            array(
                "id" => 321,
                "name" => "Item One",
                "color" => "red"
            ),
            array(
                "id" => 356,
                "name" => "Item Two",
                "color" => "green"
            )
        )
    ),
    array(
        "orderNum" => 789,
        "buyerId" => 765,
        "items" => array(
            array(
                "id" => 321,
                "name" => "Item One",
                "color" => "red"
            ),
            array(
                "id" => 356,
                "name" => "Item Two",
                "color" => "green"
            ),
            array(
                "id" => 999,
                "name" => "Item Three",
                "color" => "blue"
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And here is a quick example of how you could access the orders and items

```
foreach($orders as $order)
{
    echo "Order number: " . $order["orderNum"] . "\r\n";

    foreach($order["items"] as $item)
    {
        echo "Item Name: " . $item["name"] . "\r\n";
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb4f78eb3c9267068597160fa275247cdc01a76a)

Comment: To be fair and honest I am completely amateur at PHP and to get as far as I have with this so far, with a lot of reading, trial and error (and a few questions on here) I have actually amazed myself in getting something half usable (privately for myself on my server)  but everything is hard referenced and I used @$ all over the place instead of if statements for when a value is empty to suppress the errors)

Comment: I have come to realize the approach I took was just a "get it working as I'd like by whatever works" method and that's its all going to need a re-write as I really have learnt so much in these last few weeks/months. So yeah back to the blank canvas on reflection is probably is the best way for me putting into practice what I've learnt so far.  Thanks for the great advise, tips and example code, I'm sure ill be back soon for help!